# Report not displaying in Report Viewer

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, reporting-services

I have several reports displaying in my windows form application with no problems at all. I build them using the 'design new report' feature inside the report viewer with no code attached, other than a refresh when the page loads.

They are all working fine apart from one that is giving me a huge headache! There is nothing different with this one compared to the others as far as I can see, but this one displays 'No data available'?

There is data and I can preview it and display the data in a data grid view with no issues?

Are there certain reserved words or something that I am missing? I am trying to display the total amount of payments from customers. As simple as that?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Code for data grid view:
         //Populate payments datagrid view
        private void displayInGrid_Payments(string sqlcmd)
        {
            paymentsDataGridView.Rows.Clear();

```
        connect.Open();

        command.Connection = connect;
        command.CommandText = sqlcmd;

        reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // add a row ( get index )
            int arow = paymentsDataGridView.Rows.Add();

            paymentsDataGridView.Rows[arow].Cells[0].Value = reader["Customer_ID"].ToString();
            paymentsDataGridView.Rows[arow].Cells[1].Value = reader["Payment"].ToString();
            paymentsDataGridView.Rows[arow].Cells[2].Value = reader["Payment_Date"].ToString();

        }
        reader.Close();
        connect.Close();
    }

    //Display all payments
      private void button_display_payments_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        command.CommandText = "SELECT PAYMENTS.Customer_ID, PAYMENTS.Payment, PAYMENTS.Payment_Date "
        + "from PAYMENTS LEFT JOIN CUSTOMERS ON PAYMENTS.Customer_ID = CUSTOMERS.Customer_ID";
        string cmd = command.CommandText;
        displayInGrid_Payments(cmd);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had an issue in the past similar to this (like 5 years ago).

If you open your report rdlc file directly (it is just an XML file, open it in a text editor), and look for the datasources portion.  Make sure you do not have more than 1 listed in there, or it may cause problems like this.

I'm not sure the cause.  I was also using Visual Studio 2008 at the time.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi. I checked it in notepad++ and compared it to a report that works fine and they are identical. One data source with the correct path. Very weird and annoying? The chart refreshes and loads like normal but it is like it just can't read the data?

Comment: Paste the statements you use to render the data.

Comment: Hi Jon, sorry for the late reply, been at College. That is the thing, there is no code, other than this.reportViewer2.RefreshReport(); which I use for each reportviewer, whether it's 1, 2, 3 and so on. I just used the wizard and have no problems until this particular table. The data base was created in access and I can display the contents of the table no problem using the code that I have added above. It seems as though it just can't the data or make the calculation that I asking it to do because it does display the report, except that the report says no data available? Any ideas?